# JS RegExp not working with alphabetical chars

Tags: javascript, regex

As part of a custom WYSIWYG editor, we've been asked to implement automatic emoticon parsing if enabled. To do this, we use Regular Expressions to replace character combinations with their associated PNG files.

Here is the relevant part of the code which handles this (it's triggered by an `onkeyup` event on a `contenteditable` element; I've trimmed it back to the relevant parts):

```
// Parse emjoi:
this.parseEmoji = function()
{
    if( ! this.settings.parseSmileys )
    {
        return;
    }
    var _self    = this,
        url      = 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/',
        $html    = this.$editor.html();

    // Loop through:
    for( var i in _self.emoji )
    {
        var re = new RegExp( '\\B' + _self.regexpEscape(i) + '\\B', 'g' ),
            em = _self.emoji[i];

        if( re.test($html) )
        {
            var replace = '<img class="lw-emoji" height="16" src="'+(url + em[0] + '.png')+'" alt="'+em[1]+'" />';
            this.insertAtCaret( replace );

            _self.$editor.html(function() { return $(this).html().replace(re, ''); });
        }
    }

};
```

And here is the `regexpEscape()` function:

```
// Escape a string so that it's RegExp safe!
this.regexpEscape = function( txt )
{
    return txt.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

We define all of the emoticons used in the system inside of an object which is referenced by the char combination itself as follows:

```
this.emoji = {
    ':)'  : [ '1F642', 'Smiling face' ],
    ':-)' : [ '1F642', 'Smiling face' ],
    ':D'  : [ '1F601', 'Happy face' ],
    ':-D' : [ '1F601', 'Happy face' ],
    ':\'(': [ '1F622', 'Crying face' ],
    ':('  : [ '1F614', 'Sad face' ],
    ':-(' : [ '1F614', 'Sad face' ],
    ':P'  : [ '1F61B', 'Cheeky' ],
    ':-P' : [ '1F61B', 'Cheeky' ],
    ':/'  : [ '1F615', 'Unsure face' ],
    ':-/' : [ '1F615', 'Unsure face' ],
    'B)'  : [ '1F60E', 'Too cool face' ],
    'B-)' : [ '1F60E', 'Too cool face' ]
};
```

Now, the odd thing is that any of the character combinations which contain an alphabetical character do not get replaced, and fail the `re.test()` function. For example: `:)`, `:-)`, `:(` and `:'(` all get replaced without issue. However, `:D` and `B)` do not.

Can anyone explain why the alpha chars are causing issues inside of the RegExp?

[**Paired-back jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s373t7g1/2/)

Comment: @Tushar does not work, and breaks other replacements which worked previously when using `\\B`, that was my first thought too.

Comment: You are using `re.test` with a `g`-flag regex. You can't get consistent results in such cases. Remove the `/g` or use a copy of it without `/g` with `re.test` (when you replace, it is ok to use a `/g`-regex).

Comment: @stribizhev removing the `/g` flag yields the same result. `:)` is correctly replaced; `:D` is not.

Comment: Because `\B` requires a word character after `D`. You have a mixed type content for `\B`. This is an incorrect approach. You need to use `(?!\\w)` instead of the second `\\B`. Also, I see the same is true for the first `\\B`. You need to use `(^|\\W)` instead.

Comment: @stribizhev still no result. By your logic, `:)` shouldn't be replaced if the `\\B` is incorrect. Using this: `new RegExp( '\\B' + _self.regexpEscape(i) + '(?!\\w)' )` still produces the same result (i.e. replaces `:)` correctly, but not `B)`.

Comment: And using your edit of `(^|\\W)` only replaces when a word follows, not a word boundary.

Comment: Is there a fiddle  to see what you are actually doing? For now, I pointed out that 1) RegExp.test should not be used with `/g` flag, 2) `\B` (and `\b`, too, BTW) are context-dependent), and in most cases you are safer using "stable" lookarounds/grouped alternations.

Comment: Good, so all I said looks valid. [Here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s373t7g1/4/).

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you! It's been a long day, and I'd only replaced the second `\\B` directive as indicated, not both. Using your code from the updated jsFiddle works a treat. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\B` is context-dependent, if there is a word character starting the pattern a word character must appear before it in the input string for a match. Same way at the end of the pattern, `\B` at the end of the pattern will require the same type of the symbol appear right after.

To avoid that issue, a lookaround-based solution is usually used: `(?<!\w)YOUR_PATTERN(?!\w)`. However, in JS, a lookbehind is not supported. It can be worked around with a capturing group and and a backreference in the replace function later.

So, to replace those cases correctly, you need to change that part of code to

```
var re = new RegExp( '(^|\\W)' + _self.regexpEscape(i) + '(?!\\w)' ),
   em = _self.emoji[i]; // match the pattern when not preceded and not followed by a word character

if( re.test($html) )
{
   var replace = '<img class="lw-emoji" height="16" src="'+(url + em[0] + '.png')+'" alt="'+em[1]+'" />';
   this.insertAtCaret( replace );

   _self.$editor.html(function() { return $(this).html().replace(re, '$1'); }); // restore the matched symbol (the one \W matched) with $1
}
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s373t7g1/4/).